# What should the providerName attribute be when adding a connection string for an SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, connection-string

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2014 CTP2 to build simple webpage (using C# and the razor markup). So far the database can be accessed and viewed but any attempt by the user to add a new item to it or edit an existing item throws the following error:

```
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts".
```

for reference, this is my _Layout.cshtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js")"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Movies", "Index", "Movies")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    </ul>

    <section id="main">
        @RenderBody()
        <p>Copyright W3schools 2012. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </section>

</body>
```

this is my connection string for the database in Web.config:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Movies.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

I think the problem is with the providerName attribute. When I change it to System.Data.SqlClient the database wont display at all and I get the following error (which only occurs after stopping the debug process):

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

I have a feeling that I just have the version number at the end of of the providerName attribute wrong but I cant find out what version I would need to change it to, I've tried an extensive array of numbers but to no avail.

I'm new to this framework so please be gentle :)

Comment: Have you tried `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sections have been defined is not related to the connection string.

You are missing a `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` in your _layout.cshtml.

In any of the views you probably have a `@section Script {}` defined. You will either have to remove the `@section Script {}` from the views or add the `@RenderSection()` to _layout.cshtml.